# Laptop shutting down during Linux startup

Tags: linux-kernel, laptop

I recently bought new laptop (Acer Aspire 3 A315-51-30CB) and have this issue with Linux running on it.

The issue is that it sometimes turns off during startup. Syslog contains no entries for that boot. Happens always when running on battery and when it was turned off for longer time, but it fails even with connected adapter. Usually it needed 10 tries before it successfully started.

First I encountered this issue on Manjaro (Xfce). I tried all ACPI kernel parameters that I found. It was starting fine with "acpi=off", but touchpad and keyboard were not working.

So I tried different distro, Xubuntu. It was running fine, before I installed tlp and tlp-rwd. So I assumed it was what was causing that issue on Manjaro and uninstalled it.

Yesterday after upgrading to Xubuntu 19.04 the issue was back. But when booting with 4.18.0-18 kernel it is working fine, so the issue is only with 5.0.0-13.

This is last frame of video before screen turns of:
[image: This is last frame of video before screen turns off]

Does anyone have an idea about what causes this? Is it some power saving feature that was in tlp and now is in kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't figure out what was the issue, but with kernel 5.0.0-31 system starts normally without issues.